# 2001 Dodge Durango Acts like door is open when they are shut

Tags: electrical, dodge

On our 2001 Dodge Durango sometimes acts as if a door is open and all the cab lights come on and the bell keeps dinging even when they are all closed and we are driving.

When this happens we also can't use the power locks or power windows and to stop it I have to unhook the battery then hook it back and it is fine until it decides to happen again.

Any ideas on things I can check?

Answer (score 2):

There will be a sensor switch in the door jam, check that it can move freely and lubricate it if necessary. Also check its wiring for chaffed insulation or a corroded connector